# Ler e interpretar arquivos JSON

Tags: php, json

Estou desenvolvendo um programa no qual eu preciso ler e interpretar um arquivo JSON, que na verdade é um arquivo XML transformado em JSON. Preciso selecionar e pegar algumas informações deste arquivo JSON e guardá-los em variáveis, como por exemplo o número da nota, seu valor, cnpj do cliente etc.

Segue abaixo o arquivo JSON (editei alguns valores).

```
{
    "ConsultarNfseResposta":{
        "ListaNfse":{
            "CompNfse":[
                {
                    "Nfse":{
                        "InfNfse":{
                            "Numero":"12651",
                            "CodigoVerificacao":"ECSV-EJZZ",
                            "DataEmissao":"2017-07-25T17:51:12",
                            "NaturezaOperacao":"1",
                            "OptanteSimplesNacional":"1",
                            "IncentivadorCultural":"2",
                            "Competencia":"2017-07-25T00:00:00",
                            "Servico":{
                                "Valores":{
                                    "ValorServicos":"2350",
                                    "IssRetido":"2",
                                    "BaseCalculo":"2350",
                                    "Aliquota":"0.02",
                                    "ValorLiquidoNfse":"2350"
                                },
                                "ItemListaServico":"0107",
                                "CodigoTributacaoMunicipio":"6209100",
                                "Discriminacao":"TAXA: SERVIÇO DE VOTAÇÃO ELETRÔNICA",
                                "CodigoMunicipio":"2611606"
                            },
                            "PrestadorServico":{
                                "IdentificacaoPrestador":{
                                    "Cnpj":"41069964000173",
                                    "InscricaoMunicipal":"2427745"
                                },
                                "RazaoSocial":"INFORMATICA LTDA",
                                "Endereco":{
                                    "Endereco":"RUA 241",
                                    "Numero":"241",
                                    "Bairro":"Exemplo",
                                    "CodigoMunicipio":"2611606",
                                    "Uf":"PE",
                                    "Cep":"52030190"
                                },
                                "Contato":{
                                    "Telefone":"33254854",
                                    "Email":"exemplo@exemplo.com.br"
                                }
                            },
                            "TomadorServico":{
                                "IdentificacaoTomador":{
                                    "CpfCnpj":{
                                        "Cnpj":"00085803000196"
                                    }
                                },
                                "RazaoSocial":"EXEMPLO - AMBR",
                                "Endereco":{
                                    "Endereco":"ST 06",
                                    "Bairro":"Asa Sul",
                                    "CodigoMunicipio":"5300108",
                                    "Uf":"DF",
                                    "Cep":"15425845211"
                                },
                                "Contato":{
                                    "Email":"exemplo@gmail.com"
                                }
                            },
                            "OrgaoGerador":{
                                "CodigoMunicipio":"2611606",
                                "Uf":"PE"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

No *script* PHP eu estou conseguindo decodificar o arquivo JSON e jogá-lo para uma variável, assim como exibir as informações na tela com o `print_r` de forma organizada, mas já tentei de tudo e não consigo colocar um foreach para funcionar, pra eu conseguir pegar certos valores nesse arquivo.

Segue meu código em php:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('arquivo.json');

$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($json_data, true) . '</pre>';

//logica do foreach

?>
```

> Coloquei só um item, na verdade, são quase 50.

Comment: Poste o JSON também, já que esse XML foi convertido.

Comment: Isso aí é um XML e não json.

Comment: Com o foreach você vai percorrer determinados arrays. Pelo que entendi do seu problema, você tem que entrar nas chaves do seu JSON decodificado e chegar até o array que você quer listar. Por exemplo:

echo '<pre>' . print_r($json_data['ConsultarNfseResposta']['ListaNfse']['CompNfse'][0]['Nfse'], true) . '</pre>';

Comment: @RORSCHACH pode até ser dup de alguma pergunta que já existe no site, mas creio que não seja desta que postou, parece que usar o json_decode ele já sabe, o que ele não sabe é trabalhar com arrays e/ou objetos (`->`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa entender é que quando você decodifica um arquivo `JSON` em uma variável, esta variável se torna um objeto, e como todo objeto em `PHP`, você precisa acessar cada elemento através do `->`.
Para acessar primeiro o array e iterar através dele, você precisa primeiro acessar objeto por objeto até chegar na variável que representa a lista que contém todos os outros objetos. O script abaixo provavelmente funcionará para o seu caso, você só precisa complementar com as variáveis que deseja acessar.

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('arquivo.json');

    $json_data = json_decode($json);

    for($i=0; $i < count($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse), $i++){

        echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->Nfse->...
        echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->PrestadorServico->...
        echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->TomadorServico->...
        echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->OrgaoGerador->...
    }

?>
```

Teste o script e veja se funciona, caso haja algum problema, comenta aqui que eu ajudo.

Comment: Obrigado Cloud, eu só tive que tirar o "true" ali do decode que deu certinho.